# Python Pandas: exclude holiday days from 1min freq date range

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to make a `date_range` in `pandas` with 1 minute frequency and only on UK business days and in working hours.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279894/how-do-you-create-a-date-range-spanning-multiple-days-with-only-some-intra-day-v), I can get most of the way there:

```
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range('2016-01-01','2016-02-29',freq='1min')
rng=rng[rng.indexer_between_time('09:00','17:00')] #exclude non-working hours
rng=rng[rng.dayofweek<5] #exclude weekends
dates = rng.to_series()
```

But I'm not sure how to exclude holiday days. In other words, is it possible to pass a set of exclusion dates to `date_range`?

What I could do is create separate ranges for each working period and then `concat` them together, but I thought there might be a better way of doing it.

Pandas has an `AbstractHolidayCalendar` class for this sort of thing, but I can't figure out how to combine that with a one minute frequency. If you resample, the extra days get added back.

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CDay
import datetime

class ExampleCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules =[Holiday('August Bank holiday',month=8,day=31)]

cal = ExampleCalendar()
```

---

```
rng2 = pd.date_range('2015-04-08','2016-04-08',freq=CDay(calendar=cal))
tester=rng2.to_series()
tester2=tester.resample('1min')
t3=tester2[tester2.index.indexer_between_time('09:00','17:00')]
```

---

```
>>> len(t3['2015-08-31 09:08:00':'2015-08-31 09:22:00'])
15 #the excluded days are still present
```

Comment: Your code sample does not work please verify

Comment: @Merlin - it works for me. Which part failed for you?